# How to write reusable code for Database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, design-patterns, code-reuse

How should i write a **reusable code in Android** for Database. What pattern or architecture should i follow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Step 1: Make Always different package in Application eg(com.appname.db).
        Step 2: Create DBHelpar Class on it and Put All method relate db on it,.
        Step 3: This is All are Common Method.

i am pasting code for your reference 


package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

i this now you got it How to handle database in android.

Comment: Thanks Hasmukh: do i need to create separate Handler class for each table

Comment: no, you can create multiple table , you have write code(for table) into onCreate of DBHelpar Class..

Comment: I think that you should have a db helper class that is generic, so that it could be used as a library for multiple apps.  You might be able to subclass it, or write it so that the table names, keynames, definitions are stored in a separate class.  Also, the methods for inserting, updating, deleting, and querying the database should be written in a separate class, specifically for interfacing with the database.  Follow a SOA style, and the code will be easier to maintain, reuse, debug, and also you can then easily write unit tests.

Comment: @Hasmukh: I think we should getWritableDatabase/getReadableDatabase at beginning of each method (CRUD methods) and calling 'close' at the end of method. Do you think that?

Comment: What about transactions, how does this design fit in with transactions?