# Database callins for SQLite on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am creating an android application that requires me to call is in different classes. i have set up my database like this:

```
public class DataBaseHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "example.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
private static final String INSERT = "insert into "+ TABLE_NAME + "(name) values   (?)";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
       OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
       this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
    }

    public long insert(String name) {
       this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
       return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
       this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }

    public List<String> selectAll() {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "name" },
      null, null, null, null, "name desc");
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }
     if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
      cursor.close();
     }
     return list;
   }

   private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

      OpenHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
     onCreate(db);
   }
  }
}
```

if i was to call this in a different class how would i go about doing it. and would i need to change this class any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simple,,jst create object of DB class and use that method..like.

```
DataBaseHelper db=new DataBaseHelper(this) ;
db.insert("HellooAndroid");
db.deleteAll();
```

**See this Link for more Reference:**

[How to write reusable code for Database in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785563/how-to-write-reusable-code-for-database-in-android/9785657#9785657)

Comment: and will that allow me to alter it in one class and the call it in another?

Comment: yes, any where you can call, but you need to object each and every class then you can use method of db class..

Comment: so if i say in class a do 'DataBaseHelper db=new DataBaseHelper ;db.insert("HellooAndroid");' then in class b do 'DataBaseHelper db=new DataBaseHelper ;db.deleteAll();'. then will that effect the same informataion

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that: Create a class that extends Application. Create a singleton to save your application context. Then edit your database class and replace your context by the one you have in the Application.

Here is an example of what I want to say:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static MyApplication instance = null;

    public MyApplication()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    /**
     * Instanciates the class and initializes the variables
     *
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a singleton of the current class
     *
     * @return Returns the app's context
     */
    public static Context getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null) instance = new MyApplication();

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then when you need an app context (Not an activity context!), you can call MyApplication.gesInstance()

Then, when you need to insert a entry in your database, just call:

```
DataBaseHelper db_h = new DataBaseHelper() ;
db_h.insert(AnObject);
db_h.deleteAll();
```